# Failed to resolve library after upgrading the build version to 7.0

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I have upgraded the my exiting project Gradle version from older version to **"com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.4"**.

After upgrading the build version some of the existing libraries not working.

I got an error like below:

> Failed to resolve: com.yarolegovich:discrete-scrollview:1.5.1 Show in
> Project Structure dialog Affected Modules: app
>
> Failed to resolve: com.redmadrobot:input-mask-android:6.0.0 Show in
> Project Structure dialog Affected Modules: app
>
> Failed to resolve: gun0912.ted:tedpermission:2.2.3 Show in Project
> Structure dialog Affected Modules: app
>
> Failed to resolve: com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.8.0
> Show in Project Structure dialog Affected Modules: app
>
> Failed to resolve: com.wang.avi:library:2.1.3 Show in Project
> Structure dialog Affected Modules: app
>
> We recommend using a newer Android Gradle plugin to use compileSdk =
> 32
>
> This Android Gradle plugin (7.0.4) was tested up to compileSdk = 31
>
> This warning can be suppressed by adding
> android.suppressUnsupportedCompileSdk=32 to this project's gradle.properties
>
> The build will continue, but you are strongly encouraged to update
> your project to use a newer Android Gradle Plugin that has been tested
> with compileSdk = 32 Affected Modules: app

Please help me to get out this error.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

in your `build.gradle.app` file there must be property called `compileSdk` which could be `31 or 32`. change it to smaller values and try again.

Comment: compileSdk already added and it's 32 but still its not working.

Comment: read the answer carefully man. you have to change it to lower value like 26

Comment: You are encouraged to always (when possible) compile with the latest available SDK. Proposing a value of 26, being 32 the latest one nowadays, is a very bad advise.

Comment: @thelawnmowerman i am not giving bad advice. i am just answering based on his question. he is using an old gradle version so he needs old sdk version as well.

Comment: @mordor619, considering that the whole point of his post is trying to update Gradle to the latest version for Android, the proper suggestion, in my opinion, would be encouraging him to upgrade everything else too...

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. But I just run the project and it ran without any problems. But the errors still persist.
I think the problem is with Android Studio cache.
However, we have to wait until the next update.

Comment: This is not really an answer and should be a comment

Answer (score 0):

Step 1:
Update the Gradle version & all libraries.

Step 2:
Remove allprojects { } from project-level build.gradle file.

Step 3:
Replace project-level repositories {} with below code

```
repositories {
    maven {
        url "PROJECT DEPENDENCY URL" Ex. : https://maven.google.com, https://jitpack.io
    }
    google()
    mavenCentral()
    gradlePluginPortal()
}
```

Step 4:
Same repositories {} code we have to add in settings.gradle file like below:

```
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
    repositories {
        maven {
            url "PROJECT DEPENDENCY URL" Ex. : https://maven.google.com, https://jitpack.io
        }
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        gradlePluginPortal()
    }
}
```

Step 5:
Sync Gradle, clean the project & run.

I hope these steps will help you to upgrade the project from the old Gradle version to the new Gradle version 7.0.+.

Answer (score 0):

Add jcenter() in your project level build.gradle like below

```
allprojects {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}}
```

and

```
buildscript {
   repositories {      
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {...}}
```

hope it works, as some of the libraries still in Jcenter()